# What method would the following form submit via? (GET vs POST)

Tags: php, web-deployment

What method would the following form submit via?

```
<label for='name'>What's your name?</label>

<input type='text' name='name' id='name>

<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

1. GET
2. POST
3. Neither (b/c no method specified)

Comment: Default method is GET if not specified. Also, you can specify what form the fields belong to by using the form attribute in the field.

Answer (score 1):

You have only provided an input and a submit button which is not enough to submit data to server.
Given the above your form will not submit.
For your form to submit, it has to be nested within the `<form></form>` tag
thus should be:

```
<form>
    <label for='name'>What's your name?</label>

    <input type='text' name='name' id='name>

    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

you can specify a method attribute to determine if the form should be submitted via GET or POST like so:

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for='name'>What's your name?</label>

    <input type='text' name='name' id='name>

    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither

To use method u should add tag `<form>` with parameter `method`.

For example

```
<form method="POST">
<label for='name'>What's your name?</label>

<input type='text' name='name' id='name>

<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```